# Support US Government for Office 365 Management API

Tags: azure, office365

When I ingest data through Office 365 Management API ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-managment-apis-overview)), I use login.windows.net as authentication endpoint, and manage.office.com as API request endpoint.

But for Government region, it doesn't work cause for different region, the endpoint is different. However, I didn't find any useful information from Microsoft's official documentation.

Please help me if anyone had successfully connected to Government region. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For authentication endpoint, can you try login.windows.us?

Comment: @GauravMantri login.windows.us cannot found...