# Do API gateways work normally with Office 365 U.S. Government plans?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

According to https://products.office.com/en-us/government/compare-office-365-government-plans, the US gov version of office365 is in a segmented cloud, and i found an old SO question suggesting a possible issue regarding management API specifically [Support US Government for Office 365 Management API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558109/support-us-government-for-office-365-management-api)

Does anyone know whether the API gateways such as graph.microsoft.com outlook.office.com/api, manage.office.com/api, as well as the ones for OneDrive/SharePoint etc. are expected to work normally with office365 gov?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response.  We just updated out documentation on this.  These APIs should work for Office APIS through Microsoft Graph (for the most part). See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Good to know. It also sounds like i might run into issues for the non Graph calls i make (i.e. outlook API,EWS API, manage API), is that correct?

Comment: This doc is for Microsoft Graph.  There may be separate documentation with endpoint and support information from Office on Outlook, EWS and Management APIs...